# Why didn't the USA attempt to take down the missile heading for Monument/Havenrock?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

Doesn't the US military have the world's best nuclear defense capabilities? And even if they didn't, I'm sure that a satellite or two could've been used to detect that Russia had just set off a nuke. So why didn't they even attempt to shoot it down (or however else nuclear defense technology works- i.e. directing it into the sea, desert or another sparsely populated area) and why does it seem like ARGUS is the only authority existing in the Arrowverse?